# Android studio: NoClassDefFoundError with java.util.Base64

Tags: android, android-studio

Apologies, I've scanned the many similar-sounding questions and none of them have helped me.

I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1, I'm a newbie, I'm following the online tutorial "HelloWorld" program but then adding a call to java.util.Base64.getDecoder().   This fails at runtime when I run it on my actual phone (Samsung Galaxy S8):

```
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/Base64;

               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.util.Base64" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.skedgo.helloworld-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

I have in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="27"/>
```

I have:  Compile SDK Version:  API 26: Android 8.0 (Oreo)

How can I solve this problem?

I was under the belief that "java.util.Base64" was part of the standard Java library, at least for the version I'm using, so I shouldn't need to do anything special to use it.  I don't know anything about Gradle but I know that I'm using it.

Answer (score 20):

replace `java.util.Base64` with `android.util.Base64`.  android doesn't use openjdk or oracle jre so the standard packages may not be there.

Comment: how to change it?

Comment: what is 'it' that you want to change?

Comment: how to change the Ljava.Base64 to android.util.Base64 for android API 23?

Comment: search and replace?  i'm not sure i understand the question.  android.util.Base64 is there since API level 8.  java.util.Base64 is not in the android runtime.

Comment: @Jayen 
I am facing the same issue, but the java.util.Base64 call is within a third party lib
-> I created a multidex-config.pro file and added a keep rule
-keep class android.util.Base64
But at runtime, the java.util.Base64 class could not be found
How can I manage to keep the reference to the java.util.Base64 class in the primary dex file?

Comment: @true-mt  i think you have to fork the third-party lib and change the code to use android.util.Base64

Answer (score 8):

Just replace

```
import java.util.Base64;
```

with

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

And then modify your code to something like this (just an example):

```
String encoded = Base64.encode(someString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)); // for encoding
String decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT)); // for decoding
```